# Get matrix index from array index

Tags: python, math

I am trying to get a matrix index from an array index

Example: I have a 3*2 matrix

```
a b

c d

e f
```

which as array can be written as `[a,b,c,d,e,f]`.

From the position of element in array say 5th, I want to get the position in matrix which in this case is 3*1

Please Help!

Comment: Are you able to add any code you have tried? You are more likely to get responses that way.

Comment: I haven't tried any code. It might be simple math which I am unable to figure out!

Answer (score 0):

Use integer division and remainder

```
row = i // width
col = i % width
```

Comment: do you mean
i as the index of array, width as the length of the array?

Comment: i is index in 1d array, width is number of columns in 2d array - in your case 2. Note that numeration in Python starts from zero, so i=5 corresponds to element f and position 2,1

Answer (score 0):

```
def GetRowAndColum(iNoOfRows,  iNoOfColumn, iIndex):
        #Floor division to get row
        iRowInMatrix = iIndex//iNoOfColumn
        iColumnInMatrix = iIndex % iNoOfColumn
        return iRowInMatrix, iColumnInMatrix


mat = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
iNoOfColumn = 2
iNoOfRows = 3

iIndex = 5
i, j = GetRowAndColum(iNoOfRows, iNoOfColumn, iIndex)
print "Row in matrix: ", i
print "Column in matrix: ", j
```

### **OutPut:**

[Tryouts]$ python TestMat.py
Row in matrix:  2
Column in matrix:  1

I have assumed matrix with zero based index. If your index starts with 1 then simply add 1 to row and column index.